# DetectedActivityFence not triggering?

Tags: android, triggers, broadcastreceiver, android-geofence, google-awareness

As the title suggest, I'm trying to use the new Awareness API, which works great but the DetectedActivityFence that never gets triggered, no matter what I do, sometimes it gets triggered immediately after it gets registered and that's all. Tried with Moto G (XT1032) and a Galaxy S4 (GT-I9500).

Other fences like HeadphoneFence work just fine. Snapshot API works fine too so it's very frustrating.

Any advice would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar issue at the moment. Did you ever manage to find out what was going on?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538912/google-play-fence-api-activity-only-working-for-a-short-period

Comment: Nope, I'm going to need this API again in a short time, so I'll be updating this as soon as I get anything new